# Wordpress not showing posts older than 2 days

Tags: wordpress, posts

I am recently experiencing a very odd bug.
I have created some custom fields for my posts and just realized that posts older than 2 days don't show anymore...if I change the date to yesterday or today, they reappear...

Here's the code I wrote to show my posts:

```
<?php
$partnersId=array();
$argSections = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'category' => '38',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$postsSections = get_posts($argsSections);
foreach ($postsSections as $postSections):
    setup_postdata($postSections);
    $idPartner = $postSections->ID; ?>

    <div class="row box_agenda_filter" data-filter="<?php echo get_field('section_filter_',$idPartner); ?>">
        <div class="event_time event_time_red">
            <span><?php echo get_field('partner_type_',$idPartner); ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="info_text pseudo_element">
            <a href="<?php echo get_field('partner_website_',$idPartner); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_field('partner_logo_',$idPartner); ?>" style="width:200px; height:auto; position:relative; margin:20px 0;"/></a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php echo get_the_content($idPartner); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you added posts in same category `'category' => '38',`?

Comment: `'category' => '38'` is supposed to be `'cat' => '38'`. As per documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: @gufranhasan Yes I am sure cause once I change the publish date to less than two days, it's working like a charm.

Comment: @designtocode Not sure that might be the issue here since I've been using category instead of cat on my entire website and it's working like a charm.